How to access key and value from redis using RedisJSON module in python
I have records stored like below in the Redis.
‘monitor':{'105894288': {'status': 'Screen', 'release': '23.4.5'},
 '106521147': {'status': 'Screen', 'release': '23.4.5'},
 '106521148': {'status': 'Screen', 'release': '23.4.5'},
 '106521149': {'status': 'Screen', 'release': '23.4.6'}
}

Here, monitor is the root key and numbers are ids. I would like to retrieve whole record including the ids using RedisJSON query in python. How to retrieve it? The example answer for release 23.4.6 is '106521149': {'status': 'Screen', 'release': '23.4.6’}

You can simply use json.get() function for retrival.
below is the example solution for your problem.
assuming you have "redis" already installed.
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, decode_responses=True)
result = r.json().get('monitor', '$.*[?(@.release=="23.4.6")]')
print(result)

this should get you your result.
1 basic assumption in this is that the key - "release" will always have unique values.

For me it returns empty list of records. Another query I tried is $[?(@.release == "23.4.6”)], It returns only values of dict like {'status': 'Screen', 'release': '23.4.6’}. Not the id.  Also, can you explain what do you mean by “release” will always have unique values.
